# Resource id cannot be an empty string

Tags: android, embedded-resource

I am an absolutely beginner in Android coding. In Messages Gradle Build, I got error:

> Resource id cannot be an empty string (as 'id' with value '@+id/').

The highlighted string is:

```
android:id="@+id/">
```

However, the string seems to created automatically by Android Studio.
Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 7):

You must add a name after `@+id/`

Something like

```
@+id/idname
```